How to project top view and side view from the point data (created from xyz file obtained from preprocessing of point cloud data) in QGIS?
I need to create two rasters (top view and side view ) from the point data I obtained by pre-processing the point cloud data from RiSCAN pro. I know that for top view I need to project it to XY plane and for side view I need to project it to XZ plane . However I have no idea how to do it in QGIS as I am new to this software and I need this for my thesis. It would be a great help if someone guide me on how do I create those two views and rasterise them for further analysis.
